# Storing data correctly in Azure Cosmos

Tags: database-design, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a database which has two "Containers" one for "Users" and another for "Posts":

**Users :**

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "Peter"
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "Paul"
}
```

**Posts:**

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "My First post"
    authorId : 1
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "My Second post"
    authorId : 1
}
```

If a user wants to like a post, so user 2 likes post one, where should that data base saved? Should the Post item be updated to keep a reference of who likes that post in an array? If so what happens when millions of people like this post?

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "My First post"
    authorId : 1,
    usersWhoLikeThis: [2,130,2341]
},
```

Should that data be stored on the user details e.g.:

```
{
   id: 2,
   name: "Paul",
   postsILike: [1,15,82,800]
}
```

Or should this information be storied in its own Container:

**Likes:**

```
{
   id: 1,
   userId: 2,
   postId: 1
},
{
   id: 2,
   userId: 2,
   postId: 2
}
```

But this would mean I would have to query that database twice, once to get the list of posts and then a second query to get the list of likes for a user and work with two data sets and check the 'likes' data set against each postId to see if it exists.

Does anyone have any tips or examples on the best way of storing data like this?

Many thanks

Comment: While there is no "right" answer, you did identify an important limitation / anti-pattern: an *unbounded array*  (such as an array representing everyone who "liked" a post, in your example) will eventually grow beyond the maximum size of a document, breaking your app and your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would model post and likes as a single container with postid as the partition key, then use a "type" property to distinguish "post" from "like". Each new post is an insert and each like is an insert. A query such as "Select * from c where c.postid = "xxx" returns the original post plus an array of likes.

Depending on your scenario you could also model this such that the "post" item contains a "likes" property that is a count for each like that get's incremented on each insert from Change Feed. This totally depends on how your app works.

For instance, if people scroll posts and can see the total number of likes before clicking into them, then you'd probably want to increment on each new like and update each post. Then your query for a feed page would be "select * from c where c.type = 'post'". Please note, that this would be a cross-partition query in the model below. Again you would look to use Change Feed to potentially put data into a separate container with a partition key that can easily answer queries with single partition queries.

In short, here's how I'd model this.

Posts container

```
{
    id: "xxxxx",
    postId: "abcdef"
    title: "My First post"
    likes: 2,
    userId : "aaaa",
    type: "post"
},
{
    id: "xxxxx",
    postId: "abcdef"
    userId : "bbbb",
    type: "like"
},
{
    id: "xxxxx",
    postId: "abcdef"
    userId : "cccc",
    type: "like"
},
```

I would generalize authors to just be users and put in same container.

We have an example implementation to build a blog engine on top of Cosmos DB. That is very similar to what you are trying to do. Please see, [How to model and partition data on Azure Cosmos DB using a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it heavily **depends on how you want to read / write** the data. Your posts probably just need to display the like count in the first place and want to prevent users from liking a post more than once.

So you could store the likes inside the user to ensure it can like a post only once. Then you could use a stored procedure or change feed to update the like count on a post.

However, if your read / write use case is different, the database design would probably also change...

Read more about:
[Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)